# imagemagick: how to change image's background color with anti-aliasing

Tags: images, imagemagick, anti-aliasing

> [image: fox]

I want to keep the fox only. That is to change the image's white background color to transparent with imagemagick.

The anti-aliasing is intractable , the image's edge is of sawtooth.

I tried it out.

Here is code:

```
convert fox.jpeg -alpha set -channel RGBA \
-fill none -opaque white fox_one.jpeg 

convert fox.jpeg -matte -fill none \
-draw 'color 0,0 replace' fox_two.jpeg
```

Both failed with that

[image]

I did it according to [color_basics/#replace](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace).

Any more accurate docs recommended?
And How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, [unlike your previous question regarding icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1286061/how-to-replace-colors-shape-color-and-background-color/1286158#1286158), there are many ways to approach background removal with more complex images... so there may not be a single "good" solution. That said, for the example you posted, here are some approaches that may be more satisfactory.

---

*Though I give my suggestions below, there are likely much better ways to do things which I am currently unaware of. Please forgive any mistakes, omissions or things I may have overlooked. =)*

---

**Simple Single-Color Transparency**

To convert a single color (e.g. background) to be transparent, you can use:

```
convert fox.jpg -transparent white fox_transparent.png
```

However, this yields the same results as your bad image, which is undesirable:

*ex. fox_transparent*

[image: fox_transparent_nofuzz]

This is because the areas in white (above) are not really white (they are off-white, mostly due to anti-aliasing as you've noted). To fix this, one possible option is to use [-fuzz](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz) to select pixels that are *almost* (nearly) white:

```
convert fox.jpg -fuzz 11% -transparent white fox_transparent_fuzzed.png
```

This produces better results:

*ex. fox_transparent_fuzzed*

[image: fox_transparent_fuzzed]

---

**Better Edges (?)**

While a simple use of `-fuzz` may work well enough, there can still be undesired roughness:

*ex. fox_transparent_fuzzed - Rough Edges*

[image: fox_transparent_fuzzed_jaggies]

To address this issue, we can use a [mask](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/) that has been blurred to help soften the edges of the image.
To do this in one step, [we can take some code from this forum post](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24108) and use it like so:

```
convert fox.jpg ( -clone 0 -fuzz 11% -transparent white -blur 0x1 ) -compose copy_opacity -composite fox_transparent_fuzzed_blurry_mask.png
```

This command creates a blurred mask which is then composited with the original image. This is the result:

*ex. fox_transparent_fuzzed_blurry_mask*

[image: fox_transparent_fuzzed_blurry_mask]

You can see that the edges are softer now:

[image: fox_transparent_fuzzed_nojaggies]

If necessary, we can do something similar in two steps:

```
convert fox.jpg -type Grayscale -negate -fill white -fuzz 11% +opaque "#000000" -blur 0x1 fox_blur_mask.jpg
convert fox.jpg fox_blur_mask.jpg -compose copy_opacity -composite fox_transparent_blur_mask_result.png
```

The first command:

- Creates a black and white version of the image (`-type Grayscale`).
- (Effectively) inverts the colors for masking purposes ([-negate](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#negate)).
- Uses `-fill white -fuzz 11% +opaque "#000000"` to fill in the fox's head with white (so we can see most of the original image).
- Applies a light `-blur 0x1` to the image.

This is the mask produced, with everything in black becoming transparent in the final image:

*ex. fox_blur_mask*

[image: fox_blur_mask]

The second command simply combines the original image and the mask together to get this result:

*ex. fox_transparent_blur_mask_result*

[image: fox_transparent_blur_mask_result]

You will note that the result is nearly identical to the "all together" example given earlier:

[image: fox_transparent_fuzzed_blurry_mask]
[image: fox_transparent_blur_mask_result]

---

*Caveats*

- *As already noted, the suggestions given aren't the only ways to accomplish things and there may be alternative/better versions of the commands given.*
- *These examples assume there is no transparency in the original image. If there is, you may have to use different options/commands. Likewise, these suggestions have only been tested with .jpg files as the input format and .png files as the output format.*
- *The basic drawback to `-fuzz` is that it is hard to apply in a consistent fashion. `-fuzz 11%` is what works best for the example image. `-fuzz 10%` or `fuzz 12%` would likely leave unwanted stray pixels. Other `-fuzz` values will likely be needed for other images.*
- *These suggestions don't address any approaches to keeping certain parts of an image which are the same color as your background (such as the fox's white eyes). For this, you would likely either want to A) alter the mask in the final example or B) if you wanted something like the second example from the top, use e.g.*

  ```
  convert fox.jpg -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -fuzz 11% -fill none -floodfill +0+0 white -shave 1x1 fox_flood_2_minimal.png
  ```
- *Note that the command above was copied from the [masking](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/) link already provided.*

Comment: Quite contented. I am an iOS developer. I want to know OX, especially OS X. So I try something intuitive. I don't know how to ask questions ,like a pro , or right.

Comment: Curiousity is an admirable trait, I think. Someone will never know the right questions if they don't ask at all. =) In any case, I am glad this was helpful. Good luck! =)